# Objective C: Class Extensions and Protocol Conformation Warnings

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a large class, which I have divided into several different class extension files for readability.

```
@protocol MyProtocol
@required
-(void)required;
@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject <MyProtocol>
@end

@interface MyClass (RequiredExtension)
-(void)required;
@end
```

Is there a better way to do this, without the compiler warning?

```
 warning: class 'MyClass' does not fully implement the 'MyProtocol' protocol
```

Comment: Your question seems to ask how to get around the error, if you're asking how to implement extensions then you should say so.

Comment: Your answer did help, but the warning are present again if you define the original class implementation (But you can define it also as a class extension as well to silence all warning. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a category for each protocol implementation. I use this when I have complex viewControllers.

For example, I have a category that implements NSTextDelegate protocol.

So, MyComplexViewController+NSTextDelegate.h:

```
#import "MyComplexViewController.h"

@interface MyComplexViewController (NSTextDelegate) <NSTextDelegate>

@end
```

and MyComplexViewController+NSTextDelegate.m:

```
#import "MyComplexViewController+NSTextDelegate.h"

@implementation MyComplexViewController (NSTextDelegate)

- (BOOL)textShouldBeginEditing:(NSText *)textObject{
    ...
}

- (BOOL)textShouldEndEditing:(NSText *)textObject{
    ...
}

- (void)textDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)notification{
    ...
}

- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification{
    ...
}

- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{
    ....
}

@end
```

Then I take all the headers for the main class definition and the categories and combine them into one header which I then import where I need to use the class.

Answer (score 3):

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@end

@interface MyClass (RequiredExtension) <MyProtocol>
-(void)required;
@end
```

Adopt the protocol in the category.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change your style of coding.  To get around the warning, it only need to implement "required" method of the protocol, not "optional"

Answer (score 0):

If that's only for readability, you should use categories only. A protocol is not needed in such a case.